# Vue3/Vuex - Component not reflecting state change when using destructuring assignment

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, mutation

I am using Vue 3 with Vuex. I am unable to get Vue to react to a change in state when mutating the state via destructuring assignment. Though, I *am* able to get Vue to react when I change state via a mutation that only reassigns a single value.

**Am I doing something incorrectly?**

**The following code works**

I have a component that pulls in a Vuex getter in `setup()`:

```js
const someValue = computed(() => store.getters['app/getSomeValue'])
```

The code below dispatches the action that mutates this value and *will* react just fine:

```js
store.dispatch('app/setSomeValue', newValue)
```

The mutation:

```js
setSomeValue(state, value) {
  state.someValue = value
},
```

**The following code does *not* work**

What if I wanted to alter multiple properties of a module's state without having to rely on multiple mutations? I'd use object destructuring. The following code, when logged, shows that a state change does happen, but neither the component that uses it nor Vuex devtools reflects a change.

1. The action being dispatched:

```js
store.dispatch('app/setSomeValue', { someValue: newValue })
```

2. The mutation using destructuring:

```js
setState(state, payload) {
 state = { ...state, ...payload }
}
```

Now, I shouldn't even have to change the getter. Though using this method, Vue doesn't pick up on a change. If I log state after I use destructuring, it shows `someValue` as being updated. What gives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reassigning the entire `state` object must be breaking reactivity or otherwise causing Vuex to lose track of state changes somehow.

Use [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) to copy the key-values from your payload to your store's state while maintaining the same original `state` object in memory.

```js
setState(state, payload) {
  Object.assign(state, payload)
}
```

Comment: Apparently with destructuring assignment, I am creating a NEW object. Vue keeps track of the OLD object, therefor never picks up on what this new object should contain. Thanks for your answer, as it is correct.